# Clean up a Regex pattern to use as a meaningful error message to user

Tags: c#, regex, validation

I'm having a pickle with Regex patterns. What I've got in my code, is a data entry method using Regex to validate. This has gone well, but I am trying to show an error message as below with an example error.

```
string rule = "\bPartNumber-\w-SN\d{6}\b"
MessageBox.Show("Error, the validation has failed. Text should resemble: \n\n" + rule);
```

Output on the message box reads exactly how the pattern exists. So what I am trying to do, is remove the "\b"'s as they have no meaning to the user. But replace the other expressions such as \w \d \d{6} with @ for any character, or # for any number. Something more meaningful to the end user.

All help is greatly appreciated.

[Additional] I've attempted using the Regex.Replace methods, but either I'm not understanding it correctly, or I cannot get the patterns correct to find...the patterns.

Comment: Any attempt to do that replace?

Comment: I've been trying replace, but I can't figure out the pattern to find..a pattern. :(

Comment: I doubt it will be possible in a single replace. I believe you'll need several processes to get your desired output. Otherwise, a first step for removing all the `\b` shouldn't be too difficult, right? And substituting `\w` with `@` and `\d` with `#` should be easy enough for second and third steps.

Comment: Don't forget you need to put a @ in front of the string if you are going to use "\" otherwise it is the `string` escape character, and not the `regex` escape character.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks Jerry, this was the approach I was trying, but I was struggling to get around the escape character issues. But what Sam has suggested does work. I've self taught myself c# only been working with her for about 2 months, so still learning such basic tricks. Thanks Guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem resolved, using the `@` key before my regex rule as reminded by Sam, my pattern  worked as I expected.

```
string rule = @"\bPartNumber-\w-SN\d{6}\b"
MessageBox.Show("Error, the validation has failed. Text should resemble: \n\n" + rule);
```